# Android SDK tools rev 19: Issue with external jar files

Tags: classpath, noclassdeffounderror, apk, android-sdk-tools

I know this question was asked a couple of times on stackoverflow - but I still face some problems trying to add an additional jar file to an existing android project - using android sdk tools rev. 19.

Summary:

- I use eclipse Version: 3.6.2
- The project compiled and the artefacts worked with android sdk tools rev. 14/any android >2.2 (>= API 8)
- The project does compile with sdk tools rev. 19/any android >2.2 BUT the artifacts do not contain the jars defined within the classpath - so I keep getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exceptions
- I tried to add "jar.libs.dir=lib" to my project.properties - since lib contains all the jars without any positive effect.
- I also tried to create a new dummy project adding jars as I always did  (all jars added to a lib folder within the project, right click on the jar > add to build path)
- I tried to add the jars using import

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your "lib" folder to "libs".